# Is there other options to work with video editing than ffmpeg in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, video

I have an app that creates video montages. I'm using FFmpeg to make the montages but I would like to know if there is other packages that could accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [`video_manipulation`](https://pub.dev/packages/video_manipulation) package offers an alternative (for iOS only) and is not supporting `ffmpeg` because:

> FFmpeg won`t be implemented due to licensing, extra overhead from the ffmpeg binaries and overall slow performance.

The package is based on `AVFoundation`.

2. The [`tapioca`](https://pub.dev/packages/tapioca) package offers another alternative (for Android and iOS) and is currently based on `AVFoundation` for iOS and `Mp4Composer-android` for Android.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking something for Android, actually. But in the future I plan to support iOS also.

Comment: I've edited the answer adding another package that supports both Android and iOS

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thank you so much.

Comment: "Tapioca" is a food in Brazil 